# How can I imitate @Inject by classes.methods calling?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I would like to unit test a class that gets some configuration normally created by @Inject annotation from javax.inject.Inject.

Instead, I thought about the configuration instance at the start of the test by calling some classes.methods. It should be possible, for somehow, the constructor of the class **is** called.

instead of

```
@Inject
@Named ("reportsprops")
protected Configuration reportsprops;
```

, described in META-INF.spring as:

```
<bean id="reportsprops"
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String"
        value="file:${spr.root.dir}/reports.properties" />
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="throwExceptionOnMissing" value="true" />
    <property name="reloadingStrategy">
        <bean
            class="org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to use in the unit test something as:

```
Configuration reportsprops = a_direct_call_of_constructor 
or something similar, usable in test without running the server and things
```

As the config is really great, I need to fill it from the file as the Spring fills it, without hand mocking the hundreds of separate properties. Something as

Beans.createClass(Configuration, beanPropertiesFile);

Comment: You're saying the `Configuration` constructor code does something that is needed for the test to run, so it's not enough to mock it?

Comment: If you use constructor based injection this is trivially simple (but very tedious)

Answer (score 0):

The way I prefer is to use Mockito to do the injection for you

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) // or @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) for junit 4
class YourTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private YourTestedClass sut;

    // this is a mock that will get injected into the sut
    @Mock
    private Configuration yourConfig;

    @BeforeEach
    void mockConfigData() {
        when(yourConfig.getPropertyX()).thenReturn("value");
    }
}
```

You can of course actually create an instance of `Configuration` and initialize it manually.

```
class YourTest {
    private YourTestedClass sut;
    private Configuration configuration;

    @BeforeEach
    void initSut() {
        configuration = new Configuration();
        sut = new YourTestedClass(configuration);
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas. The project I am working on is a real, old, huge chunk of code and settings. That config has hundreds of properties. So, mocking them by hand is out of the question. The second way gives me the empty object. I need to fill it from the file as the Spring fills it, without hand mocking the hundreds of separate properties. Anyway, thanks for the try.

Comment: @Gangnus And running a Spring test and actually `@Autowire`ing is also out of the question? Those do take longer to run, but sounds like it might be the best you can do.